# How to use a specific version of flutter for build apk, when i have 2 version of flutter install?

Tags: flutter, dart

So i am installing both version of flutter, version 2 and, 1.22.6 , i want to build apk for my 1.22.6 project, but flutter automatically call the version 2 for building apk, this create error, what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this [Flutter version manager](https://fvm.app)

Answer (score 0):

You can create alias for Flutter and point to different version
for example
flutter will call flutter 1.22.6
flutterd will call flutter 2 instead

so when you want to build for 1.22.6 just use flutter
I have write a article, sadly in Thai not translate yet, how to have 2 different version of Flutter and how to make alias to call different version here

https://medium.com/kbtg-life/%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B9%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%88%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%81-flutter-2-0-%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B6%E0%B8%A2%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%87-%E0%B9%81%E0%B8%A5%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%A7%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%B3%E0%B8%A2%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%87%E0%B9%84%E0%B8%87%E0%B9%83%E0%B8%AB%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%84%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B7%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%87%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%B5%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%B1%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%87-2-%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%A7%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%A3%E0%B9%8C%E0%B8%8A%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%99-de861c810d57?source=your_stories_page-------------------------------------

so after you this, you can just run
flutter build

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem in the past. So what I did was, I downloaded both versions of flutter say (flutter2.2 and flutter1.22). And I have kept them in same folder. Now if I want to use flutter 2.2 then I'll rename "flutter2.2" folder to "flutter" and If I want to use flutter1.2 then I'll rename the "flutter1.2" folder to "flutter"

In the environment variable path I have set the path to "flutter/bin" so if I rename flutter2.2 to flutter then my environment variable will automatically take 2.2 version.

You may need to restart your PC after changing the version.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is:
Download the version of Flutter you need and put it in the place where Flutter is installed
In this directory you have **"flutter" folder**.
In Ubuntu, it is usually located in this path:
/home/username/development/flutter
To develop the software with the desired version, just change the desired folder name to "flutter".
For example :
flutter --> flutter-2.x.x
flutter-3.x.x ---> flutter